# Can I use the free VMWare Player for work?

Tags: licensing, vmware-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I was never good at reading and understanding commercial licenses, so I would like to ask a question. I just started working for a large company and I need to setup an environment on a virtual machine. I would like to use the free VMWare Player, but I'm not sure if I can: does the license allow me to do use the free version for commercial purposes?

Comment: Perhaps you should get $BigCompany to provide you with the tools required to do the job.

Comment: Just use Oracle VM VirtualBox instead.  No licensing dilemma for commercial use.  Just lack of features, but it's a solution.. see #2 in the licensing guide   https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to 3molos answer, not without written agreement from VMware.

From the EULA: http://www.vmware.com/download/eula/player31.html

"VMware Player is intended for your own personal non-commercial use only.  Player may only be used commercially or be re-distributed with written agreement from VMware. Requests should be submitted online at www.vmware.com/go/ playerdistribution."

Comment: Just to add to this...from my expereience they issue written permission to anyone who asks for it, you do not have to jump through any hoops.

Comment: I do not think this is the case anymore, not for recent versions. Player-specific EULA is nowhere to be found, "about" dialog invites you to buy a license for commercial use, and [the FAQ mentioned in another answer](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs.html) has no mention of "written permission" exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

[You might want to read their FAQ](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs.html).

> What does it cost?
>
> VMware Player is free for personal non-commercial use. VMware Player is only distributable with written permission from VMware. Please apply here to request a distribution agreement.